# copies a rails app to a new computer: rails command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash

I have just set up ruby and rails on a freshly installed freeBSD. It works great. I can do `rails new blabla` mv into blabla and do `rails s` and it just works.

I had an up and running rails app on another computer. I copied the repertory that contained the app to the new computer running freeBSD. However, when I mv into that repertory of the rails app and to `rails server` I get `-bash: rails: command not found`

I have tried creating a new app with the same name and let rails create all the repertories and then copy the files of the existing rails app therein but no success.

I can run `rails -v` and `rails s` from within any repertory and get correct answer, but when I move into that specific repertory I get that `command not found`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using a ruby version manager I suspect (rbenv/rvm)? Check the ruby version in your Gemfile (top of the file). It probably isn't the same as the ruby version you have installed. If you're using one of the above mentioned version managers than install the correct ruby for your rails project. After that you can do a `gem install bundler` in the project directory and after run `bundle install` which will install rails and all dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Which version you are using? It happens with earlier versions. Try updating your gems and bundler. And try again. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running `bin/rails s`? I think tha you need run `bundle install` too.